# How to register mysql cursor in java?

Tags: java, mysql

Hi , Registering Oracle cursor in java is as follows:

```
statement.registerOutParameter(4, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

How to register cursor from MySQL in java? What is the 'Type' for that?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a MySQL equivalent of registering a cursor like with Oracle. The [MySQL's Connector/J docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) says this about **statements**:

> MySQL does not support SQL cursors, and the JDBC driver doesn't emulate them, so setCursorName() has no effect.

Though cursors are supported in stored procedures and functions.

Comment: Thanks Jon. So the output from a MySQL procedure or function can be a ResultSet/any other data type right.

Comment: @Marshal Yes, I believe so, but I've never used cursors with MySQL.